# Sort grouped rows - Google sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

Is there a way in google sheet to sort rows containing groups without the groups being messed up?

For this dataset:

[image]

Using regular sort, I get this result:

[image]

I need to somehow sort the parent rows (A,B,C), without affecting the child rows. Still the children should move along with the parent.

I am looking for a way to get this result (manually sorted for this question)

[image]

Comment: Are the parent rows always denoted by a single letter A,B,C etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by sorting on the parent plus the row number like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(filter(A2:B,A2:A<>""),filter(vlookup(row(A2:A),{if(len(A2:A)=1,row(A2:A)),A2:A},2,true)&text(row(A2:A),"00000"),A2:A<>""),1))
```

[image]